# How to add a value label in each grouped barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the data I have:

```
totaldt <- data.frame(
  year = c(2023, 2022, 2021, 2023, 2022, 2021), 
  var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("knowrate", "outrate"), class = "factor"), 
  rate = c(0.616693826, 0.60826895, 0.611211938, 0.795008913, 0.820111343, 0.808219178)
)
```

First time using dput, sorry if I made a mistake. I am trying to add a value label in each group from the plot that I made. So, I want the respective value to show on top of each bar.
The code I am using is:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = totaldt, aes(fill=(factor(year)), y=rate, x=var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width=.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=rate),
            angle=90,
            check_overlap = TRUE,) +
  labs(title = "Rates, MU Total",
       x = "",
       y = "Percentage",
       fill="Year")
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

However, only one value is appearing and it appears in the wrong spot. Notice that the value appearing is relative to the year 2023, and it is on top of 2022 (green). How can I make all values appear on top of each respective bar? I hope I am making my question clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dodge the text as well

```
ggplot(data = totaldt, aes(fill=factor(year), y=rate, x=var)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width=.6), width=.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=rate),
            angle=90,
            check_overlap = TRUE, position = position_dodge(width=.6)) +
  labs(title = "Rates, MU Total",
       x = "",
       y = "Percentage",
       fill="Year")
```

[image]